# Javascript Regex, finding numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Sorry this is so specific but I couldn't figure it out from any of the examples I've seen or other questions.  I need to find all positive or negative numbers with decimals of any precision in a string. examples:  -0.2, .2, 3.4, -3.4, 3.400, 300.5 etc.  They must have decimals, no digits and no commas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, I think it should be simple but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: I'm drawing a blank but nothing like 5, -1, 100

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
/\-?\d*\.\d+/
```

It will still work for `-.2` not sure if you want that.

```
\-?        - or no -
\d*        0 or more digits
\.         .
\d+        1 or more digits
```

Also if you're sure the entire string will be the value with no other characters, then you should add `^` and `$`

`/^\-?\d*\.\d+$/` would not match something like `'hello1.2'` whereas without `^` and `$` it would match.

Comment: @nschamb1, Since the answer **agreco** provided worked for you, you should [accept his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and possibly [upvote it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/when-you-accept-an-answer-should-you-also-vote-it-up) as well! Also see [When should I vote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote) and [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Answer (score 0):

try this one,I just test it in regex coach,fits your example:

```
"[^\d]\.\d+|[-|\d+|-\d+]\d*\.\d+|\.d+"
```